# How do we do a DBMS OUTPUT line in db2 (like you can in oracle)

Tags: db2

In Oracle we can print output by `dbms_output.put_line()` but I don't know to do the same thing in DB2.

I currently use `signal` for printing some messages when I debug.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a row in a permanent debug table or in a declared global temporary table (DGTT). You could also write a simple Java stored procedure that stores a line of text to a file.

When DB2 9.7 is released (sometime in June 2009) it will automatically come with the dbms_output feature as part of DB2's new "SQL dialect" support (a.k.a Oracle compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select 'message' from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```